# How to Store Each Coordinates into Two Dimensional Array Android

Tags: android

There is Method `onTouchEvent()` in Android. I get `x` and `y` Coordinates from this method. I want to store each Coordinates into Two Dimensional Array. How should I do it? Any Suggestions ??

Below is My Code

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.e("TAG", "Action down :==>>"+ x + "," + y + "");
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.e("TAG", "Action up:==>>"+ x + "," + y + "");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
            Log.d("TAG","Action was CANCEL");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
            Log.d("TAG","Movement occurred outside bounds ");
            return true;
        default :
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's better to store point x,y in ArrayList<ClassObject> type, if you have fixed size array than you can use array

Comment: class Points{
int x,y;
//getter & setter
}
than ArrayList<Points> obj = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: for array int[][] points = new int[no of points][2];
               ////    
for x , points[index][0]=x
                    ///////
for y , points[index][1]=y

Answer (score 2):

Create POJO class for storing coordinates

```
public class CoordinatePoint {
    int x, y;

    public CoordinatePoint(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Now create `ArrayList<CoordinatePoint>` in your activity and you can create and store objects in it. You can either use the constructor or set values of `x` and `y` using setter methods to your CoordinatePoint Object. And get the assigned values using the getter methods.

**Edit** As suggested by @pskink you can also use `Point / PointF` class to achieve functionality you want without creating a separate class. check the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PointF).

Comment: Thanks its very helpful :)

Comment: you dont need such a class: use `Point` / `PointF` classes instead

Answer (score 1):

Why should you use 2D array?

You can declare Coordinates class which contains X and Y

then make a List

After that just keep adding it list.add(coordinates), much simpler than 2D array

Comment: I want to make Ludo Board so i need each box's Position that's why i need to store it in 2 dimensional array